PyMuPDF Pixmap.set_dpi not working properly
I am trying to change the quality of the pages of a pdf with PyMuPDF and make a comparison between the new sizes. I noticed that if I change the dpi with the method Pixmap.set_dpi nothing happen. Instead, by recomputing the Pixmap another time, with Page.get_pixmap, than it works properly.
I assume that Pixmap.set_dpi works in-place but its effect seems not affect the Page-object.
Example 1: using Pixmap.set_dpi (doesn't update the size)
import fitz


src = # path of the pdf
dpi = 200
with fitz.open(src) as doc_src:

    for page in doc_src:
        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        size_old = pix.size
        
        pix.set_dpi(dpi, dpi) # <-- doesn't update the size
        size = pix.size
        
        rate = size / size_old - 1
        shape = ("+" if rate >= 0 else "-") # detect increment / decrement
        rate_percentage = f"{shape}{abs(rate) * 100:.2f}"

        print(page.number+1, f"{dpi=}: {size_old} -- {rate_percentage} --> {pix.size}")
        break

Output (the increment is not +0.00 as shown in Example 2)
1 dpi=200: 1454208 -- +0.00 --> 1454208

and
Example 2: calling twice Page.get_pixmap
src = # path of the pdf
dpi = 200

with fitz.open(src) as doc_src:

    for page in doc_src:
        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        size_old = pix.size
        
        pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=dpi) # <-- 2nd call
        size = pix.size
        
        rate = size / size_old - 1
        shape = ("+" if rate >= 0 else "-") # detect increment / decrement
        rate_percentage = f"{shape}{abs(rate) * 100:.2f}"

        print(page.number+1, f"{dpi=}: {size_old} -- {rate_percentage} --> {pix.size}")
        break

Output (correct output)
1 dpi=200: 1454208 -- +671.56 --> 11220096


Tested on PyMuPDF 1.23.16 and 1.25.1.

Thanks for your remarks. I think the origin of my confusion is on how should I know if the dpi-value passed to get_pixmap is going to increment or decrement the density? For example, if I set the result of get_pixmap().size without any explicit values of dpi as a default value, then how should I know, without doing a trial and error method, that get_pixmap(dpi=90).size is going to reduce or increment the density? Is the value of get_pixmap().size just meaningless?

yes, I also found it out that get_pixmap is defaulted to dpi=72... and now I know why:)
